# Why does git log --find-object get two file commits with different content for a given blob?

Tags: git, object, hash, blob

I am using `git log --find-object` to [identify commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590251) by providing git file blobs (file content hashes).

This works usually fine, I get the blob before for a file by using `git hash-object`.

However, sometimes for a given blob hash of a file, `git log --find-object=<blob>` returns two commits for the same file, where the contents of the files of the returned commits definitely *differs*.

Getting multiple commits where the corresponding files contents is the same I would expect, but having commits reported where the content is *not exactly the same* seems odd to me (that is based on how I would understand the `--find-object` option atm).

Why is that? Where would I have to elaborate with the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---find-objectltobject-idgt) (also refer to the [-S and -G option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Sltstringgt) to make sense of it) :
with this option, a commit will be mentioned if the number of occurrences of said object *changes*.

So, if you take the `blobid` of a file in your repo (say, the blobid of file `Readme.md`)

`git log --find-object=<blobid>` will :

1. report commits where this `blobid` appears as file `Readme.md` (that's what you expect),
2. report commits where that blob *disappears* as file `Readme.md`, eg : a commit which changed the content of `Readme.md` *from* `blobid` to something else ;
3. report commits where this blob appears or disappears at some *other path*, eg : at some point, file `doc/Doc.md` had the exact same `blobid` ;
4. *not* report commits where a file with that exact content has been renamed, eg : file `doc/Doc.md` has been renamed to `Readme.md`, or from `Readme.md` to `doc/Doc.md`

---

You can run :

```
git ls-tree -r <commit> | grep <blobid>
# check parent commit too :
git ls-tree -r <commit>^ | grep <blobid>
```

to see which `<commit>` contained that blob, and at what path.

If you want to check what modified the precise path `Readme.md`, you can add it as a filter to `git log` :

```bash
git log --find-object=blobid -- Readme.md
```

This will get rid of cases 3. and 4. above.
You would still see commits where the content you look for is in the parent commit (case 2. above).

Comment: A rename won't change the number of occurrences of some blob hash ID, so this doesn't find renames unless you limit the `git log` to looking for a particular pathspec (without `--follow`).

Comment: @LeGEC: Thanks, I was unaware of the 'disappearing' counting part of git log. Not super intuitive - but then again, it is git... :)

Comment: I reworded my answer, to take into account @torek's remark, and hopefully make it clearer for other people.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more precise than [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64251164/1256452) although that one covers the most common case.  What `git log --find-object` does is find commits where, from parent to child, the commit *changes the number of occurrences* of that particular blob.

Suppose, for instance, we create a new empty repository with one initial commit with a README file:

```
$ mkdir tlog
$ cd tlog
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in [path]
$ echo test find-object stuff > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 2177143] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

Now let's create a blob, commit it, and observe its hash ID:

```
$ echo file content > afile
$ git add afile
$ git commit -m 'add some content'
[master 45c4e39] add some content
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 afile
$ git rev-parse HEAD:afile
dd59d098638313f5d00a7fa657379b33b191f2e2
$ blobid=$(git rev-parse HEAD:afile)
```

Now let's make a commit that doesn't change the *number of files* that have that blob hash ID, by adding a file with different content, then add a third file with the same content—hence same blob hash ID—as the first file:

```
$ echo different > bfile
$ git add bfile && git commit -m 'add different content'
[master c5a5306] add different content
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 bfile
$ cp afile cfile && git add cfile 
$ git commit -m 're-add same content as afile, ie, same blob id'
[master 20c97e5] re-add same content as afile, ie, same blob id
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 cfile
$ git rev-parse HEAD:cfile
dd59d098638313f5d00a7fa657379b33b191f2e2
```

As you can see, the same hash ID comes up again.  (In fact, any repository with a file that matches my `afile` or `cfile` has that blob hash ID in it!  The *commits* will have unique hash IDs, but any file that reads `file content` plus a single newline will have blob hash ID `dd59d098638313f5d00a7fa657379b33b191f2e2`.)

Now let's look at `git log --oneline` and `git log --oneline --find-object=$blobid` output:

```
$ git log --oneline
20c97e5 (HEAD -> master) re-add same content as afile, ie, same blob id
c5a5306 add different content
45c4e39 add some content
2177143 initial
$ git log --oneline --find-object=$blobid
20c97e5 (HEAD -> master) re-add same content as afile, ie, same blob id
45c4e39 add some content
```

We see commit `45c4e39` in both cases because comparing `2177143 initial` to `45c4e39 add some content` shows that the *number of files* that have `$blobid` as their object hash has gone from zero to one.  We see `20c97e5` because comparing that commit to its parent, `c5a5306`, shows that the *number of files* has gone from 1 to 2.  If we remove one copy, the count will change again and we'll see that commit.  If we remove *both* copies, the count will change (to zero) and we'll see *that* commit.

What we're seeing, in other words, is *every commit in which the count of blob objects with the given hash ID changes*.

There's a bug, of sorts, in this `git log` option: it relies on the fact that each of these commits has *one single parent*.  If we have a *merge commit*—a commit with two or more parents—Git has to compare the blob hash IDs in the merge to *both parents*.  Perhaps the count changes in one comparison but not in the other.  What should Git do with this?  Git's current answer is that it craps out completely here—hence "bug of sorts"—but with a fix that's in the queue, you get something that's *better* but still imperfect, as there's no obvious Right Answer for this case.  (The bug is that Git is going through a special code path in `git log` that's meant to handle History Simplification, and that's the wrong thing to do here.  The proposed fix makes Git go through a more suitable path, so that you'll at least see that the merge has *some* change in the count, which is clearly significantly better.  But that leaves other cases for other options that don't always work right, too.  Git needs a general solution for diffs-across-merges, and that requires a framework that currently does not exist.)

Comment: Great elaborate answer!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result of that command might change with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020): "`git log -c --find-object=X`" did not work well to find a merge that involves a change to an object `X` from only one parent.

See [commit 957876f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/957876f17d75b5cd0e94b85d3df843bb1e9ae110) (30 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7da656f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7da656f1e083b065400c4ab92405c6332481eb7a), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`combine-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/957876f17d75b5cd0e94b85d3df843bb1e9ae110): handle --find-object in multitree code path
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When doing combined diffs, we have two possible code paths:
>
> - a slower one which independently diffs against each parent, applies any filters, and then intersects the resulting paths
> - a faster one which walks all trees simultaneously
>
> When the diff options specify that we must do certain filters, like pickaxe, then we always use the slow path, since the pickaxe code only knows how to handle filepairs, not the n-parent entries generated for combined diffs.
>
> But there are two problems with the slow path:
>
> 1. It's slow. Running:
>
>    git rev-list HEAD | git diff-tree --stdin -r -c
>
> in `git.git` takes ~3s on my machine.
> But adding "`--find-object`" to that increases it to ~6s, even though `find-object` itself should incur only a few extra `oid` comparisons.
> On `linux.git`, it's even worse: 35s versus 215s.
> 2. It doesn't catch all cases where a particular path is interesting.
> Consider a merge with parent blobs `X` and `Y` for a particular path, and end result `Z`. That should be interesting according to "`-c`", because the result doesn't match either parent. And it should be interesting even with "`--find-object=X`", because "`X`" went away in the merge.
>
> But because we perform each pairwise diff independently, this confuses the intersection code. The change from `X` to `Z` is still interesting according to `--find-object`. But in the other parent we went from `Y` to `Z`, so the diff appears empty! That causes the intersection code to think that parent didn't change the path, and thus it's not interesting for "`-c`".
>
> This patch fixes both by implementing `--find-object` for the multitree code.
>
> It's a bit unfortunate that we have to duplicate some logic from `diffcore-pickaxe`, but this is the best we can do for now. In an ideal world, all of the `diffcore` code would stop thinking about filepairs and start thinking about n-parent sets, and we could use the multitree walk with all of it.
>
> Until then, there are some leftover warts:
>
> - other pickaxe operations, like `-S` or `-G`, still suffer from both problems.
>   These would be hard to adapt because they rely on having a `diff_filespec()` for each path to look at content. And we'd need to define what an n-way "change" means in each case (probably easy for "`-S`", which can compare counts, but not so clear for `-G`, which is about grepping diffs).
> - other options besides `--find-object` may cause us to use the slow pairwise path, in which case we'll go back to producing a different (wrong) answer for the `X`/`Y`/`Z` case above.
>
> We may be able to hack around these, but I think the ultimate solution will be a larger rewrite of the `diffcore` code.
> For now, this patch improves one specific case but leaves the rest.