# question about a git big blob that look like not used

Tags: git, gitlab, git-filter-repo

Following the documentation in [gitlab doc: reducing_the_repo_size_using_git](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) I'm cleaning a repo from GitLab, so I exported it, got a link by email, downloaded and untared it.

```
aaa_export$ git clone --bare --mirror  project.bundle
Cloning into bare repository 'project.git'...
Receiving objects: 100% (109830/109830), 627.15 MiB | 63.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (89023/89023), done.
aaa_export$
$ du -sh project.git
633M
$
```

Then I Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
Enumerating objects: 109830, done.
Counting objects: 100% (109830/109830), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (108121/108121), done.
Writing objects: 100% (109830/109830), done.
Selecting bitmap commits: 13458, done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (238/238), done.
Total 109830 (delta 89020), reused 19482 (delta 0)
$
$ du -sh project.git
633M    # Not a surprise this working copy came from a gitlab export
$
```

By curiosity I look for the biggest blob in my repo:

```
$ git verify-pack -v objects/pack/*idx |sort -n -k3 |tail -3
24c41d1b2132daac9a13910f839173da3890c991 blob   13464592 8520894 149667646
28678d4814faecf8c20a3c893e1ac93cd159a289 blob   19558229 19538291 167335758
8103683624212caadee8e609295addd24ec43db1 blob   21805631 15702989 237885293
$
```

And so I try to got commit objects list from the bigger blob:

```
$ git cat-file -t 810368362
blob
$
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep 8103683624
$
```

Same when using a `git whatchanged` as exposed in [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
$ git whatchanged --all --find-object=8103683624
$
```

So I'm very surprise to have this big blob that correspond to nothing:

```
SHA-1                                    type   size     size-in-packfile offset-in-packfile
8103683624212caadee8e609295addd24ec43db1 blob   21805631 15702989         237885293
```

How can I know what is this blob for ?

Note: We are here in a **bare repository** so git log diff and describe does not apply that's why [which-commit-has-this-blob/#VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590251/3313834) with the `git log --find-object=<object-id>` does not apply here, btw the which-commit-has-this-blob question is around *create a central Git repository* not about understanding how a big blog is refering to no commit/tree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)

Comment: No it doesn't I've explained in the question the difference