# Is there a way to determine what branches are associated with a given blob?

Tags: git

When using `git cat-file --batch-check` with a given commit-id object, how can one determine what branches or tags a blob belongs to ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't—not "when using `git cat-file`", that is.

If you widen the question, you can get *much* closer: [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223678/1256452)

Once you have the commit hash IDs—and you say you're *starting* with commit hash IDs, so you may not even need to look up the blob hash IDs—you can get all containing branch names, for each commit hash ID, using `git branch --contains`.  (Use `git tag --contains` or `git tag --points-at` for tags, depending on what you want for your answer; see also `git for-each-ref` as well, and [VonC's suggestion of using `git describe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027778/1256452).)

Depending on which of the various solutions you like from the linked question, you can start from branch names before examining the tree associated with each commit to find whether that commit contains the blob; by working backwards from branch names, to commit hash IDs, you already know which branch name(s) contain that commit.

Comment: thx torek, for responding and need to ponder your response