# How to access commit hash instead of temp file path in git diff tool script

Tags: bash, git, shell

I have the following configuration for `git difftool`:

```
[diff]
    tool = any
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "any"]
    cmd = /maxkoretskyi/test/my.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

inside `cmd` I have access to several variables like `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` that I pass to `my.sh`. Those are temp file paths and my script outputs them simply like this `echo "$1" "$2"`:

```
$ git difftool git difftool 821d1b06 73a14711
Temp/NviQKc_f1.txt 
Temp/exkQKc_f1.txt
```

Is there any way to access the commit hashes in `my.sh` that a user passes to `git difftool command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`difftool` is not what you want; this program operates on file contents, and has no access to metadata. Rather, look into the [`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITEXTERNALDIFFcode) environment variable

Quoting from the manpage:

> GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
>
> When the environment variable GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is set, the program named by it is
> called to generate diffs, and Git does not use its builtin diff machinery. For a
> path that is added, removed, or modified, GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is called with 7
> parameters:
>
> `path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode`

The hex values on the `GIT_EXERNAL_DIFF` command line are blob object id's, not commit id's; See the related question [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678) (eg. `git log --find-object=<blob>`)

**NOTE** the same blob id can occur in multiple commits, so it's not possible to uniquely identify which of the commits was referred to on the "`git diff <commit> <commit>`" command line

Comment: thanks, so there's no way to get this info using `difftool`?

Comment: I can't say **there is no way**. If you had to make the SHA1's available to the mergetool, you can modify the script `libexec/git-core/git-difftool--helper` to pass in extra arguments, define environment variables, etc. There are ways, although they are hacky and are likely to cause you headaches with future versions of git. Sticking to documented features would minimize such headaches. It's also possible to maintain your own fork of git which functions to your specifications. I think most users would avoid these ways.

Comment: Maybe if you describe what you're trying to do, there may be a better solution.

Comment: just tested, it outputs hash of the file, not the commit id that I pass, `$ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF="./my.sh" git diff 821d1 73a14`

Comment: The hashes on the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` command line are blob object id's. You can search the repo for commits which contain these blobs (there may be more than one commit). See [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)

Comment: got it, worked for me, thanks!