# Meaningful names using git difftool?

Tags: git

I'm not entirely sure if this is an issue with git difftool, but when I use it with a custom difftool it shows random prefixes to the filename I'm diffing on both sides. uZl7iq_README.txt vs hO7k5f3_README.txt, for example. I'm pretty confident that left and right correspond to the first and second commit hashes that I provide to difftool, and of course a little investigation proves/disproves that, but it would be really nice if the prefix could reflect the either the branch name I provided or the commit it resolves to. Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, depends on the details of the diff tool.

`git diff` is aware of Git and can look up the contents of particular revisions in Git on its own and display the filename from Git.

`git difftool` uses an external diff program of your choice. These programs know nothing about Git. `git difftool` writes the contents to be diffed to temp files. Then it runs a script to execute the diff program. $LOCAL and $REMOTE are the temp files to be diffed. $MERGED and $BASE are name of the file in Git. You can see these by using the `echo` difftool.

If there is a way to tell the diff program "diff $LOCAL and $REMOTE, but pretend they are actually called $MERGED", then yes, you can write a wrapper script which will display the Git filename.

Comment: It seems like it would be possible to write a script that intercepts the call to the difftool and renames $LOCAL and $REMOTE appropriately, but how would the script know the commits to which local and remote refer to?

Comment: It seems other have looked but not found anything compelling, at least not a simple setting or parameter or one-liner that provides the desired behavior, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361761/how-to-access-commit-hash-instead-of-temp-file-path-in-git-diff-tool-script